Wiremock has null requesthandler when testing multiple classes
I am attempting to upgrade one of my projects to use Spring Boot 3. The code is running with no issues and all of my tests pass when run individually or I run tests from only a single class.
The issue appears when I attempt to run multiple test classes in the same run. The first test to be run that calls wiremock's stubFor() function will succeed, as will all other tests in that test's class, but any test from a different class that calls stubFor() will fail with the following error:
`2024-11-26 22:55:42.258Z  WARN   --- [qtp213383793-95] o.e.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel    : {} /__admin/mappings

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
"com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.RequestHandler.handle(
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.Request, com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpResponder, com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.ServeEvent)" 
because "this.requestHandler" is null
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.servlet.WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.service(WireMockHandlerDispatchingServlet.java:165)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1614)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$MappedServlet.handle(ServletHandler.java:1547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.dispatch(ServletChannel.java:824)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.handle(ServletChannel.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Sequence.handle(Handler.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:979)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1164)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)`

Expected status 2xx for http://localhost:8089/__admin/mappings but was 500
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: Expected status 2xx for http://localhost:8089/__admin/mappings but was 500

This issue has no effect on any test that does not call stubFor, those always pass no matter when they are run.
WireMockClassRule is instantiated as specified in the wiremock documentation, and I am using JUnit 4.13.
@ClassRule
public static WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(8089);

@Rule
public WireMockClassRule instanceRule = wireMockRule;


Are you using the latest version of WireMock and the Jetty12 JAR?

I was using wiremock-jetty12 3.9.2. I just attempted to use version 3.10, which was just released and had the same result.

I can't replicate this from the info you've posted. Can you post the full details needed to reproduce this in a GitHub issue?
